# Amplify cli - "amplify push" does not update backend environment

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Node Version: v20.11.1 | Npm Version: 10.5.0 | Git Version: 2.44.0.windows.1 |Amplify Version: 12.10.1 | Operating System: Windows 10 | Vscode IDE

I setup my storage using the amplify cli command `amplify storage add` , when I try to `amplify push` it does not push in the backend (terminal does not show any errors) resulting with the storage category not being created in the backend environment. I only have one backend environment right now called dev.

I have followed the amplify [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/storage/configure-storage/)  and this [one](https://docs.amplify.aws/javascript/build-a-backend/storage/set-up-storage/) and have configured storage, when I use `amplify status` this is the result:

```
Current Environment: dev
┌──────────┬───────────────────────┬───────────┬───────────────────┐
│ Category │ Resource name         │ Operation │ Provider plugin   │
├──────────┼───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Api      │ myProject             │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Auth     │ myProjectfc38077a     │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
├──────────┼───────────────────────┼───────────┼───────────────────┤
│ Storage  │ myProjectStorage      │ No Change │ awscloudformation │
└──────────┴───────────────────────┴───────────┴───────────────────┘
```

The first time I `amplify push` I get no errors, everything is successful, but when I check the amplify console the Storage category was not published.

I have tried `amplify storage remove` and `amplify storage add` again and still same end result.

I have deleted my `node_modules` and `amplify` in my project, ran `npm install` and `amplify pull` and tried to start over again creating storage and still the same problem.

My project API and AUTH are still functioning as expected.

This is what my `amplifyconfiguration.json` file looks like:

```
{
  "aws_project_region": "ap-southeast-2",
  "aws_appsync_graphqlEndpoint": "https://xxx.appsync-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
  "aws_appsync_region": "ap-southeast-2",
  "aws_appsync_authenticationType": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
  "aws_appsync_apiKey": "xxx",
  "aws_cognito_identity_pool_id": "ap-southeast-2:xxx",
  "aws_cognito_region": "ap-southeast-2",
  "aws_user_pools_id": "ap-southeast-2_xxx",
  "aws_user_pools_web_client_id": "xxx",
  "oauth": {
    "domain": "xxx-dev.auth.ap-southeast-2.amazoncognito.com",
    "scope": [
      "phone",
      "email",
      "openid",
      "profile",
      "aws.cognito.signin.user.admin"
    ],
    "redirectSignIn": "http://localhost:9000/",
    "redirectSignOut": "http://localhost:9000/",
    "responseType": "code"
  },
  "federationTarget": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
  "aws_cognito_username_attributes": [
    "EMAIL"
  ],
  "aws_cognito_social_providers": [],
  "aws_cognito_signup_attributes": [
    "EMAIL"
  ],
  "aws_cognito_mfa_configuration": "OFF",
  "aws_cognito_mfa_types": [
    "SMS"
  ],
  "aws_cognito_password_protection_settings": {
    "passwordPolicyMinLength": 8,
    "passwordPolicyCharacters": []
  },
  "aws_cognito_verification_mechanisms": [
    "EMAIL"
  ],
  "aws_user_files_s3_bucket": "xxx132512-dev",
  "aws_user_files_s3_bucket_region": "ap-southeast-2",
  "API": {
    "GraphQL": {
      "endpoint": "xxx.appsync-api.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/graphql",
      "region": "ap-southeast-2",
      "defaultAuthMode": "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS"
    }
  }
}

I've been stuck for this for a while so I might have overlooked a simple step or something. Thank you
```

Comment: It should "just work". You may want to do something that will cause the status for Storage to be 'changed', for example `amplify update storage` and

Comment: Thanks for your input  @Dave, sorry I forgot to mention that I have tried that also and it's still the same result.